# Trying to execute multiple stored procedures in multiple calls in parallel from .net core WebApi

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been trying to find a way to execute stored procedures in SQL Server in parallel from a web API in .net core. The requests are being done by an Angular project.

My method, in my webapi, in the lowest level that actually makes the call looks like this:

```
public static async Task<List<dynamic>> CollectionFromSp(this DbContext dbContext, string SpName, List<SqlParameter> SpParameters)
{
    List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString);

    using (connection)
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SpName, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(SpParameters.ToArray());

        using (var dataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                var dataRow = GetDataRow(dataReader);
                result.Add(dataRow);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And this is how I would call it from a top layer:

```
public async Task<List<dynamic>> GetDataGastoTotalPorGrupo(DashboardParamsDTO parameters)
{
    var lparams = new List<SqlParameter>()
    {
        { new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@BankId" , Value = parameters.BankId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt } },
        { new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@ViewType" , Value = parameters.ViewType, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit } },
        { new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@MonthId" , Value = parameters.MonthId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int } },
        { new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@BrandId" , Value = parameters.BrandId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int } },
        { new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@MonthIdFrom" , Value = parameters.MonthIdFrom, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int } },
        { new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@MonthIdTo" , Value = parameters.MonthIdTo, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int } }
    };

    List<dynamic> list = await DynamicConnection.CollectionFromSp(CTBdc, "dbo.usp_ResumenMensual_ListaGastoTotalPorGrupo", lparams);
    CTBdc.Database.CloseConnection();
    return list;
}
```

I have six requests made from my Angular project and each one in the end uses the first method "CollectionFromSp", but with different parameters.

The thing is, each one of these six requests takes about 6 or 8 seconds if I call them one by one from Postman, but when I call all six at the same time from my Angular project it takes about 50 seconds to finish everything, like they are being executed sequentially. In Chrome DevTools I can see the slowest one taking a lot more time. What's weird to me is that in SQL Server Profile I can see all six "RPC:Starting" events appearing at the same time.

So, is this a normal behavior and I have to optimize my queries? Maybe my DB server is not strong enough to execute everything quick enough? Or am I doing something wrong, either in my backend or in the DB and it should be possible to execute everything in the 6 to 8 seconds that takes the slowest SP?

Comment: 6-8 seconds for a request is too much, if your app is for many users using, that will cause a big problem, usually each one should take less than 1 second. That's the sign of how bad it is and you really have to find a way to improve that speed. If the app is just for several users using (like an administrative tool), that speed then is OK. Also trying to execute concurrently multiple requests from one single client should be taken carefully, e.g: ensure that the number of concurrent users is not too high. You have good speed but with a trade-off of lesser concurrent users.

Comment: @King That time is because of the amount of data my user requires and the amount of rows there is in the tables for my query. Can I improve my query and the time? Probably, but that is not my question here.